# PHP Docker Vendor Autoload.php not found

Tags: php, docker, nginx, composer-php, dockerfile

I am trying to setup the Dockerfile for PHP services. PHP scripts are served using Nginx server in docker container but its giving me vendor/autoload.php not found error.

I have tried changing Dockerfile several times but the vendor/autoload.php error still persists.

Here is the **Dockerfile**

```
FROM composer as builder

RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/php-services
WORKDIR /usr/app/php-services
#copy composer file
COPY composer.json .


RUN composer install

#copy php-scripts to /usr/app/php-services
COPY . .


FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/php-services /usr/app/php-services
COPY ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

#check if vendor has autoload file and it exists!!!
RUN ls /usr/app/php-services/vendor

EXPOSE 8000
```

The scripts should work fine but whenever I run docker logs it says.
[image]

Here is the **nginx.conf** file

```
server {
listen 8000;


access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;


root /usr/app/php-services;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

I have tried almost everything and have literally no idea why this is happening. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any issue in my nginx.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the last response, I misunderstood the problem.

However I was able to build a similar container but wasn't able to reproduce the error. It might be something with the php-scripts you are adding that aren't in this post. I was able to get a similar container build though using modified copies of your Dockerfile + nginx.conf. I also added some debugging for troubleshooting in the Docker file and created a launch/build script.

I edited the Dockerfile to have the following. This will add setting 755 permissions if you need, listing out a few directories in question and your log. If needed post that output to comments.

```
FROM composer as builder
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/php-services 
WORKDIR /usr/app/php-services
COPY composer.json . 
RUN composer install
#copy php-scripts to /usr/app/php-services
COPY . .
COPY php.ini /usr/app/php-services
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/php-services /usr/app/php-services
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
COPY php.ini .
#check if vendor has autoload file and it exists!!!
RUN chmod 755 -R /usr/app/php-services;ls -lrt /etc/nginx/ /var/log /usr/app/php-services/  /usr/app/php-services/vendor /usr/app/php-services/vendor/twitter.php;/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log | tee -a shellcheck.log
    #CMD ["ls -la /usr/app/php-services/vendor"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

Then edited nginx.conf to have the following. Added resolver information (unsure if this will apply to you or not) including upstream property, try_files, including snippets for fastcgi.

```
    server {
listen 8000;
resolver 127.0.0.11;
set $upstream php-fpm:9000;
access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;
root /usr/app/php-services;
location / {
try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass  $upstream;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Then created a shell script to launch build and report back some debug info. Add this next to the Dockerfile on docker host, make it executable with chmod +x run-container.sh then run it with ./run-container.sh $PORTNUM. ie ./run-container.sh 8000

```
    #!/bin/bash
docker build . -t php-services:v3 
docker run -d -p $1:8000 php-services:v3
CONTAINER=`docker ps -a | head -2 | tail -1| awk '{print $1}'`
echo "Your container is: $CONTAINER"
docker ps -a | head -2 | tail -1| awk '{print $1}'
docker cp $CONTAINER:/var/log/nginx/ .
docker cp $CONTAINER:/shellcheck.log .
docker cp $CONTAINER:/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf .
docker ps -a  | grep $CONTAINER
docker logs  $CONTAINER
```

Let me know if any of this works for you, for some reason yours is expecting a twitter.php which I do not have and wasn't an issue. Is that something you are copying into container from that folder?

Comment: Hi, I added ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/app/php-services/vendor"] but it says permission denied. If im not wrong entrypoint is used to execute any script but "/usr/app/php-services/vendor" is a directory, how's this gonna work?

Comment: Hey you are right, I see a few problems. I was thinking fast but didn't try it out myself. I am going to build it now, have a basic hello world working with a basic php.ini since you don't have attached to run the exact container.       
                        [root@docker 052319]# docker ps -a | grep 3f
3f5f3beca266        php-services:v3                                        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp       eloquent_stonebraker
[root@docker 052319]#